# Graphviz ignores rank attribute if no edges between nodes

Tags: graph, graphviz, dot

I'musing Graphviz to render some hierarchical structure. So far the use of subgraphs has been sub-optimal for achieving what I'm looking for.

**This** is what I would like to get

[image]

*(colors represent different tiers in the hierarchy so they need to follow this order)*. For making this image I used invisible links, but that's really not an option in a real world scenario.

However, at the moment this is what I'm getting
[image]

using this .dot file

```
graph {
    // Global config
    rankdir=BT
    node [style="filled" fontcolor="white" shape="box"]
    // Rank (hierarchies)
    { rank=same; 258 }
    { rank=same; 259 }
    { rank=same; 260 }
    { rank=same; 261 262 }
    // Nodes
    // Tasks
    258 [label="John Cleese" fillcolor="#E8B04D"]
    // Project Goals
    259 [label="Michael Palin" fillcolor="#C0C56B"]
    // Identities
    260 [label="Eric Idle" fillcolor="#FF8D61"]
    // Virtues
    261 [label="Graham Chapman" fillcolor="crimson"]
    262 [label="Terry Jones" fillcolor="crimson"]
    // Edges
    259 -- 260 [style="bold" color="#3790af"]
}
```

**Is it posible for Graphviz to honor rank before edges? If so, how would I proceed?**

Answer (score 4):

Your problem is easily solved by the addition of a few invisible edges that make the various ranks (that you set up correctly) work as you want.  Note the simple addition of three invisible edges near the bottom:

```
graph {
    // Global config
    rankdir=BT
    node [style="filled" fontcolor="white" shape="box"]
    // Rank (hierarchies)
    { rank=same; 258 }
    { rank=same; 259 }
    { rank=same; 260 }
    { rank=same; 261 bl 262 }
    // Nodes
    // Tasks
    258 [label="John Cleese" fillcolor="#E8B04D"]

    // Project Goals
    259 [label="Michael Palin" fillcolor="#C0C56B"]

    // Identities
    260 [label="Eric Idle" fillcolor="#FF8D61"]

    // Virtues
    261 [label="Graham Chapman" fillcolor="crimson"]
    262 [label="Terry Jones" fillcolor="crimson"]

    // Edges
    259 -- 260 [style="bold" color="#3790af"]
258--259 [style=invis]
260--261 [style=invis]
260--262 [style=invis]
260--bl [style=invis]

bl [style=invis label="" height=0, width=0]

}
```

I also added an invisible balancing node in the center, `bl` to help center the graph better.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Tom. I already have tried that and it does work. I'm actually looking for an alternative, since as I said adding these phantom edges programatically might be very complex.  If no alternative is available, I'm gonna have to do this!

Comment: @Sebastialonso Ok, thanks, see my latest edit, helps balance the graph better if that helps also.  Unfortunately, there is no way for the rendering engine to discern that the various subgraphs, even with `rank-same` need to be on *different* ranks without some kind of edge.